# Best way to redirect a macOS app url request?

Tags: proxy

I am using a device that needs to connect to manufacturers servers. To circumvent, I am running a "fake" version of that on my own server.

I want to use a desktop app (on macOS). This app will call out to the manufacturers servers (to synchronize with device, etc.). I, of courses, would also want this to go to my own server instead. But trying to modify the app seems like a bad choice for several reasons.

Is there a fairly simple way to have all requests originating from this app to e.g., https://manufacturer.website.com redirected to https://my.own.server?

Or if that's not possible/feasible, perhaps a way to do this for all traffic, then I could probably automate this to turn on/off depending on whether the app in question is running.

Comment: edit `/private/etc/hosts` to point host name `manufacturer.website.com` to the IP address of your server. It will break most HTTPS stuff, but that can usually be ignored or disabled depending on the app